# babel ignore node_modules copying node_modules to build folder

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5, babel-cli

I am trying to use es6 in my node 14+ app transpiling using babel 7.18.6. I added below build step to my npm script

```js
"build": "babel . --ignore node_modules,.platform --copy-files --no-copy-ignored --delete-dir-on-start --out-dir dist"
```

But it still copies node_modules and other unnecessary directories in root to the build folder.
I've tried different combinations in `babel.config.json` with `ignore` block but its still not working.

How to make `--copy-files` ignore node_modules and other unnecessary directories

Here is my `babel.config.json`

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "^3.23.3",
        "debug": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "./node_modules"
  ],
  "targets": {
    "node": "current"
  }
}
```

Babel packages I'm using in my package.json

```json
"@babel/cli": "^7.18.6",
"@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
"@babel/node": "^7.18.6",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
```